# A black pop up screen blocks me from doing anything in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

[image: pop up]

A pop up like above appears over all windows and I am unable to do anything on my computer.

Answer (score 2):

It was an issue with one of the media button in the keyboard. The issue is gone when I removed the keyboard.